# java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.mysql.cj.jdbc.Driver (Only occurs when installed as .jar file)

Tags: java, mysql, eclipse, maven, javafx

I am a bit new to maven and javafx. The program behaves normally whenever it is running through eclipse. However, a problem occurs whenever I clean install it into jar using maven. i come across `java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.mysql.cj.jdbc.Driver` error message. Note that the javafx part of my code runs just fine. The program starts with a login instance which opens just fine, but when I try to connect to the MySQL database by pressing "login", the following error occurs: -

```
java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.mysql.cj.jdbc.Driver
        at java.base/jdk.internal.loader.BuiltinClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
        at java.base/jdk.internal.loader.ClassLoaders$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
        at java.base/java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
        at java.base/java.lang.Class.forName0(Native Method)
        at java.base/java.lang.Class.forName(Unknown Source)
        at x.xx@0.0.1-SNAPSHOT/x.xx.xxx.MySQL_Connect.Login(Unknown Source)
        at x.xx@0.0.1-SNAPSHOT/x.xx.xxx.Login_Control$1.handle(Unknown Source)
        at x.xx@0.0.1-SNAPSHOT/x.xx.xxx.Login_Control$1.handle(Unknown Source)
        at javafx.base@19.0.2.1/com.sun.javafx.event.CompositeEventHandler.dispatchBubblingEvent(Unknown Source)
        at javafx.base@19.0.2.1/com.sun.javafx.event.EventHandlerManager.dispatchBubblingEvent(Unknown Source)
        at javafx.base@19.0.2.1/com.sun.javafx.event.EventHandlerManager.dispatchBubblingEvent(Unknown Source)
        at javafx.base@19.0.2.1/com.sun.javafx.event.CompositeEventDispatcher.dispatchBubblingEvent(Unknown Source)
        at javafx.base@19.0.2.1/com.sun.javafx.event.BasicEventDispatcher.dispatchEvent(Unknown Source)
        at javafx.base@19.0.2.1/com.sun.javafx.event.EventDispatchChainImpl.dispatchEvent(Unknown Source)
        at javafx.base@19.0.2.1/com.sun.javafx.event.BasicEventDispatcher.dispatchEvent(Unknown Source)
        at javafx.base@19.0.2.1/com.sun.javafx.event.EventDispatchChainImpl.dispatchEvent(Unknown Source)
        at javafx.base@19.0.2.1/com.sun.javafx.event.BasicEventDispatcher.dispatchEvent(Unknown Source)
        at javafx.base@19.0.2.1/com.sun.javafx.event.EventDispatchChainImpl.dispatchEvent(Unknown Source)
        at javafx.base@19.0.2.1/com.sun.javafx.event.EventUtil.fireEventImpl(Unknown Source)
        at javafx.base@19.0.2.1/com.sun.javafx.event.EventUtil.fireEvent(Unknown Source)
        at javafx.base@19.0.2.1/javafx.event.Event.fireEvent(Unknown Source)
        at javafx.graphics@19.0.2.1/javafx.scene.Node.fireEvent(Unknown Source)
        at javafx.controls@19.0.2.1/javafx.scene.control.Button.fire(Unknown Source)
        at javafx.controls@19.0.2.1/com.sun.javafx.scene.control.behavior.ButtonBehavior.mouseReleased(Unknown Source)
        at javafx.controls@19.0.2.1/com.sun.javafx.scene.control.inputmap.InputMap.handle(Unknown Source)
        at javafx.base@19.0.2.1/com.sun.javafx.event.CompositeEventHandler$NormalEventHandlerRecord.handleBubblingEvent(Unknown Source)
        at javafx.base@19.0.2.1/com.sun.javafx.event.CompositeEventHandler.dispatchBubblingEvent(Unknown Source)
        at javafx.base@19.0.2.1/com.sun.javafx.event.EventHandlerManager.dispatchBubblingEvent(Unknown Source)
        at javafx.base@19.0.2.1/com.sun.javafx.event.EventHandlerManager.dispatchBubblingEvent(Unknown Source)
        at javafx.base@19.0.2.1/com.sun.javafx.event.CompositeEventDispatcher.dispatchBubblingEvent(Unknown Source)
        at javafx.base@19.0.2.1/com.sun.javafx.event.BasicEventDispatcher.dispatchEvent(Unknown Source)
        at javafx.base@19.0.2.1/com.sun.javafx.event.EventDispatchChainImpl.dispatchEvent(Unknown Source)
        at javafx.base@19.0.2.1/com.sun.javafx.event.BasicEventDispatcher.dispatchEvent(Unknown Source)
        at javafx.base@19.0.2.1/com.sun.javafx.event.EventDispatchChainImpl.dispatchEvent(Unknown Source)
        at javafx.base@19.0.2.1/com.sun.javafx.event.BasicEventDispatcher.dispatchEvent(Unknown Source)
        at javafx.base@19.0.2.1/com.sun.javafx.event.EventDispatchChainImpl.dispatchEvent(Unknown Source)
        at javafx.base@19.0.2.1/com.sun.javafx.event.EventUtil.fireEventImpl(Unknown Source)
        at javafx.base@19.0.2.1/com.sun.javafx.event.EventUtil.fireEvent(Unknown Source)
        at javafx.base@19.0.2.1/javafx.event.Event.fireEvent(Unknown Source)
        at javafx.graphics@19.0.2.1/javafx.scene.Scene$MouseHandler.process(Unknown Source)
        at javafx.graphics@19.0.2.1/javafx.scene.Scene.processMouseEvent(Unknown Source)
        at javafx.graphics@19.0.2.1/javafx.scene.Scene$ScenePeerListener.mouseEvent(Unknown Source)
        at javafx.graphics@19.0.2.1/com.sun.javafx.tk.quantum.GlassViewEventHandler$MouseEventNotification.run(Unknown Source)
        at javafx.graphics@19.0.2.1/com.sun.javafx.tk.quantum.GlassViewEventHandler$MouseEventNotification.run(Unknown Source)
        at java.base/java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Unknown Source)
        at javafx.graphics@19.0.2.1/com.sun.javafx.tk.quantum.GlassViewEventHandler.lambda$handleMouseEvent$2(Unknown Source)
        at javafx.graphics@19.0.2.1/com.sun.javafx.tk.quantum.QuantumToolkit.runWithoutRenderLock(Unknown Source)
        at javafx.graphics@19.0.2.1/com.sun.javafx.tk.quantum.GlassViewEventHandler.handleMouseEvent(Unknown Source)
        at javafx.graphics@19.0.2.1/com.sun.glass.ui.View.handleMouseEvent(Unknown Source)
        at javafx.graphics@19.0.2.1/com.sun.glass.ui.View.notifyMouse(Unknown Source)
        at javafx.graphics@19.0.2.1/com.sun.glass.ui.win.WinApplication._runLoop(Native Method)
        at javafx.graphics@19.0.2.1/com.sun.glass.ui.win.WinApplication.lambda$runLoop$3(Unknown Source)
        at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
```

However, you can see that the library is in target\modules\ as below: -

[This is the target\modules\ directory](https://i.stack.imgur.com/AcN7Q.png)

My pom.xml is as follows: -

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

    <groupId>x.xx</groupId>
    <artifactId>xxx</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <packaging>jar</packaging>

    <name>xxx</name>

    <properties>
        <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
        <mainClass>x.xx.xxx.Main</mainClass>
        <maven.compiler.source>1.8</maven.compiler.source>
        <maven.compiler.target>1.8</maven.compiler.target>
        <mysql.version>8.0.32</mysql.version>
    </properties>

    <dependencies>
        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/mysql/mysql-connector-java -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.openjfx</groupId>
            <artifactId>javafx-web</artifactId>
            <version>19.0.2.1</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.openjfx</groupId>
            <artifactId>javafx-fxml</artifactId>
            <version>19.0.2.1</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.openjfx</groupId>
            <artifactId>javafx-media</artifactId>
            <version>19.0.2.1</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.openjfx</groupId>
            <artifactId>javafx-graphics</artifactId>
            <version>19.0.2.1</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.openjfx</groupId>
            <artifactId>javafx-controls</artifactId>
            <version>19.0.2.1</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.mysql</groupId>
            <artifactId>mysql-connector-j</artifactId>
            <version>${mysql.version}</version>
            <scope>runtime</scope>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>

    <build>
        <plugins>
        
            <plugin>
                <artifactId>maven-antrun-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>3.1.0</version>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <phase>package</phase>
                        <configuration>
                            <target>
                                <echo file="${project.build.directory}/xx.bat">start jlink-image\bin\java -jar modules\${project.artifactId}-${project.version}.jar</echo>
                            </target>
                        </configuration>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>run</goal>
                        </goals>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
            </plugin>

            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>3.11.0</version>
                <configuration>
                    <release>11</release>
                </configuration>
                <dependencies>
                    <dependency>
                        <groupId>org.ow2.asm</groupId>
                        <artifactId>asm</artifactId>
                        <version>9.5</version>
                    </dependency>
                </dependencies>
            </plugin>

            <plugin>
                <artifactId>maven-jar-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>3.3.0</version>
                <configuration>
                    <archive>
                        <manifest>
                            <mainClass>${mainClass}</mainClass>
                        </manifest>
                    </archive>
                    <outputDirectory>${project.build.directory}/modules</outputDirectory>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
            
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.moditect</groupId>
                <artifactId>moditect-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>1.0.0.Beta2</version>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <id>create-runtime-image</id>
                        <phase>package</phase>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>create-runtime-image</goal>
                        </goals>
                        <configuration>
                            <modulePath>
                                <path>${project.build.directory}/modules</path>
                            </modulePath>
                            <modules>
                                <module>${project.groupId}</module>
                            </modules>
                            <launcher>
                                <name>${project.groupId}</name>

                            </launcher>
                            <compression>2</compression>
                            <stripDebug>true</stripDebug>
                            <outputDirectory>${project.build.directory}/jlink-image</outputDirectory>
                        </configuration>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
            </plugin>
            
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-dependency-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>3.6.0</version>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <id>copy-dependencies</id>
                        <phase>prepare-package</phase>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>copy-dependencies</goal>
                        </goals>
                        <configuration>
                            <outputDirectory>${project.build.directory}/modules</outputDirectory>
                            <includeScope>runtime</includeScope>
                        </configuration>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
            </plugin>

            
        </plugins>
    </build>
</project>
```

here also is module-info.java, if that helps:-

```
module x.xx{
    requires javafx.controls;
    requires javafx.fxml;
    requires javafx.media;
    requires java.sql;
    
    
    opens x.xx.xxx to javafx.fxml;
    exports x.xx.xxx;
}
```

and below is a snippet of MySQL_Connect.java which involves connecting to the server: -

```
package x.xx.xxx;



import java.sql.Connection;
import java.sql.DriverManager;
import java.sql.PreparedStatement;
import java.sql.ResultSet;
import java.sql.SQLException;
import java.time.LocalDateTime;
import java.time.format.DateTimeFormatter;
import java.time.temporal.ChronoUnit;

import javafx.scene.control.Alert;

public class MySQL_Connect {
    
    static String url = "jdbc:mysql://192.168.100.2:3306/xxx";
    static String username = "user";
    static String password = "P@ssW0rd";
    
       public static boolean Login(String usern, String pass) {
           
           Connection mysql = null;
           PreparedStatement query = null;
           ResultSet reply = null;
        
           try{
               Class.forName("com.mysql.cj.jdbc.Driver");
               mysql = DriverManager.getConnection(url,username,password);
               query = mysql.prepareStatement("SELECT * FROM xxx.users WHERE username = ?");
               query.setString(1, usern);
               reply = query.executeQuery();
                   ..........
```

A few things i tried included:

- playing with the Java Build Path in eclipse and add the mysql connector externally in the Modulepath and in the Classpath.
- playing with the module-info.java file to see if maybe maven needs a different definition of java.sql;
- utilizing different plugins on maven that looked promising including shading and the stuff you see above.
- tried to upgrade/downgrade the connector, other plugins, and the jdk versions.
- added the "Class.forName" in the MySQL_Connect.java (a different error saying that it could not find a suitable driver to connect me to the database).
- uninstalling and reinstalling eclipse | maven | jdk.

i went through various stackoverflow threads that went through similar problems to this one but nothing seems to work. This is my first post ever on stackoverflow, i hoped i wouldn't need to do this, but i am running out of options at this point. :S

Comment: If you are using Maven to build the project you should not play with Eclipse Build Path.

Comment: You don't say *how* you're running it, but if you want to run it as *one* executable jar, you will need to put the driver into that jar with something like Maven Shade. Alternatively, use a specified classpath in the command (you *won't* be then able to use `-jar`)

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45777949/whats-the-purpose-of-uses-directive-in-java-9

Comment: It seems that in your `module-info.java` the `requires ...` statement for `mysql-connector-j-8.0.32.jar` is missing (which does not have a `module-info.class`, nor an `Automatic-Module-Name: ...`).

Comment: @g00se When i run it as a default java application using eclipse, there is no issues. In terms of Maven Shade, I attempted to use that as well, I get a different yet similar error: -

Exception in thread "JavaFX Application Thread" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: javax/naming/NamingException
        at com.mysql.cj.jdbc.NonRegisteringDriver.connect(NonRegisteringDriver.java:186)

Just to note again, the .jar runs fine until I need to communicate with the MySQL database.

Comment: @mrmcwolf According to the question you linked,  from what I understood, I have to use the "use" clause to make sure the module is available. So, I added the "uses java.sql.Driver;" statement. unfortunately, nothing changed. To be fair I am a bit new to the whole module-info.java scene.

Comment: @howlger I am a bit confused, isnt "requires java.sql;" infers that i require the connector? I apologize I am a bit new to module-info.java, elaborate more if possible.

Comment: with `uses` you declare that your module will use SPI to dynamically load an interface. it remains to specify a module that offers the corresponding implementation of the interface (the driver). this is done using the `--module-path` parameter when starting the application (if you are not using a custom jre image)